# the system won't accept my encrypted volume

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, password-protection

my volume just stopped working 3 weeks ago. It won't accept the password what is actually stored in the keychain. Strange thing is i can change the password in disk utility. I started to recovery all the datas with stellar data recovery software, and most of the stuff are working, sadly some of are just a bunch of data and without header. 2 days ago my it happened with my another drive!!!!! Im really in trouble now! :/
What can i do now?+!

Comment: You should provide how are you trying to mount the volume, error messages, what additional steps have you tried etc. so someone might check if there's something wrong with it.

Comment: Your question seems to assume that we know what you're doing. For example, you say "the password" and "the keychain", but we have no idea what you mean by these terms. Password for what? What does "keychain" mean in this context. What is the "it" that won't accept the password? What "disk utility" are you talking about? What operating system?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. "IT" was the OP (OSX mavericks). Keychain is part of the osx.
Encrypted volume is a password protected volume. When you try to mount the volume it requires a password.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved
Diskwarrior repaired the disk!